# cjs or esm for react components library

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, commonjs, es6-modules

I got a components library that will be published to npm to be consumed by a razzle app. My main question that I want opinions on best practices is, should the packages be built with cjs or esm, and what is the downsides of each?

Am I fine with only building to cjs?

Answer (score 4):

#### ESM

- Tree shaking
- More understandable in code.
- Allows lazy loading of the component
- Gives more easily the ability to import a certain part of the code.

#### cjs

- Cross build
- Supported on more environments

If its no problem for you use both. One for every environment. CJS would work on most environments.

If your target is only react or other frontends es6 gives you all the advantages above. But if you want you component to be usable in javascript webpack like legacy apps you should use cjs, also for the backend.